# Supperclass in request body - 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I want to send to my endpoint an xml object but I will have serveral types of this object and I would like to use inheritance.

My supperclass look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso(Sgr.class)
public class AbstractSgr {

  @XmlAttribute(required = true)
  protected String id;

  @XmlAttribute(required = true)
  protected String field1;

  @XmlAttribute(required = true)
  protected String field2;

  @XmlElement
  @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
  protected LocalDate startDate;

  @XmlElement
  @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
  protected LocalDate endDate;
//getters setters
  }
```

My Child class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "sgr")
public class Sgr extends AbstractSgr {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "competitions")
  @XmlElement(name = "competition")
  private List<String> competitions;

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "games")
  @XmlElement(name = "game")
  private List<String> games;
//getters setters
  }
```

And my package info:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = java.time.LocalDate.class, value = LocalDateAdapter.class),
})
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/mapping", method = RequestMethod.POST,
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> saveSgr(
      @RequestBody final AbstractSgr sgr) throws ServiceException {

      }
```

The problem is when I send the post request with my valid XML I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.readWithMessageConverters(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:645) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestBody(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:604) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:353) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

But when I change the type of sgr object to Sgr everything works fine I get the correct object. Has someone had similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think it is because your incoming XML has structure that can be marshalled only to specific sub types but not abstract types. So for each subtype, you can define request methods. You can use inheritance once it is marshalled to your specific object.